# X-Forwarded-For in Gwan

Tags: header, ip-address, haproxy, g-wan

I have read through the documentation (both API and Manual), and haven't seem to find any support by gwan for the `X-Forwarded-For` header. The only thing I have found that could be related was `REMOTE_BIN_ADDR`.

I know to get a client IP you can use `REMOTE_ADDR` however my gwan servers are behind a HA Proxy load balancer, which forwards the client IP via `X-Forwarded-For`.

Does Gwan not support this header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as we know, while widely used, the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header is not part of the RFCs. Some servers, like Nginx, are using alternatives because proxy servers can "chain" the client IP address, leading to unreliable results.

On a side note, keep in mind that HTTP headers providing an `X-Forwarded-For` value *cannot be trusted*... unless your own proxy is cleaning-up any previously setup value and adding its own. This makes this `X-Forwarded-For` header less useful than expected at first glance - and surely contributes to explain why Nginx felt the need to create its own.

G-WAN initially supported this header but we have removed this entry because we believe that it is redundant with the native G-WAN reverse-proxy and load-balancer (a feature that was implemented last year but which is still not documented as documenting and exporting the interfaces in a polished way takes time - and we want to merge this feature with protocol handlers, to simplify things).

Note that, right now, you can easily parse it from the HTTP headers exposed by G-WAN, either from a `handler` or from `servlets`.

Comment: Thanks Gil for filling me in, kinda of inconvenient to do it in a handler/script but like you said it's easily done. Is there any kind of timeline you have for the reverse-proxy/load balancer (just wondering)