# Reading non-standard request HTTP headers from gwan and OPTIONS

Tags: parsing, http-headers, g-wan

I need to read a few custom request HTTP headers from gwan.

The [X-Forwarded-For](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147503/x-forwarded-for-in-gwan) question is closest to this question; however a code snippet would be appreciated.

```
http_t *head = (http_t*)get_env(argv, HTTP_HEADERS); // set HTTP bytes range
out << "Major Version:" << head->h_maj_ver;
out << "Custom Header:" << head-> ??;
```

On a somewhat related note,  u64 x = get_env(argv, REQUEST_METHOD);
doesn't respond with an integer for OPTIONS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> a code snippet would be appreciated [to find a custom HTTP header]

From your question, I assume that you are using C++.

You should simply start from the `HTTP_HEADERS` pointer and look for the string of interest - until you reach the double `CRLF` marking the end of the HTTP headers.

Or, you can use the `READ_XBUF` value to get a pointer to the request buffer so you also have the end of the buffer with `xbuf->ptr + xbuf->len`.

There are approaching examples [here](http://gwan.ch/developers#handler) and [there](http://gwan.ch/source/cookies.c).

> get_env(argv, REQUEST_METHOD); doesn't respond with an integer for OPTIONS

It does reply with the integer value '6' for me. But I am probably using a more recent release than you so any value added in the meantime will offset the values previously found by an older version.

Comment: when you say HTT_HEADERS ptr you mean the one returned from get_env(argv, HTTP_HEADERS). re OPTIONS i did just download but i see a notice posted since jan re update. thnx.

Comment: Yes, that's how to get access to the HTTP headers' pointer. We will post a new public release this summer, with our Cloud services. There are many new G-WAN capabilities, and we don't want to dilute their value by streaming them with too many periodic releases.